# Levenshtein Distance/Custum Function in Google Sheets Query

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, levenshtein-distance

I added a function
`levenshteinDistanceDP(string1,string2)`
as a custom function in AppScript. It returns an Integer. Additionally I have the Query in a sheet:

```
QUERY(Expenses!A1:H;"SELECT A, B, C, D WHERE LOWER(H) contains LOWER("""&K3&""") ";1)
```

Complementary to "WHERE LOWER(H) contains LOWER("""&K3&""")" i want to include results where levenshteinDistanceDP(lower(H),Lower(K3)) is smaller than lets say 3.

I guess there would be a way, by adding a column to "Expenses" which uses the custom function, and the query just checks for that column. If possible I would like to do it within the query tho. Any ideas?

Edit: The idea with the extra column is especially unsuitable, since the custom function takes around a second to load in each row. For several thousand rows unfeasible, since K3 can be updated at the will of the user (me) and would then be recalculated every time. I guess that fact could jeopardize the entire idea, but maybe it runs somewhat faster in the query. One reason more to include it in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the QUERY you won't have the option to apply the Levenshtein Distance formula. What I suggest to make it more feasible is not to use your function as a custom function inside a cell but to make it calculate once with onEdit.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  var shname = e.range.getSheet().getName()
  var column = e.range.getColumn()
  var row = e.range.getRow()
  var range = e.range

  if(shname == "Expenses"){ 
   if(range.getA1Notation() == "K3"){
     var rangewords = sh.getRange("H:H")
     var words = rangewords.getValues()
     for(i=0;i<words.length;i++){
      if(words[i]=="" || words[i]==null) {return}
      else {sh.getRange(i+1,10).setValue(levenshteinDistanceDP(words[i].toString().toLowerCase(),range.getValue().toString().toLowerCase()))} //change 10 with the number of column you desire to use as auxiliar for this
     }
    }
   else if(column == 8){
    sheet.getRange(row,10).setValue(levenshteinDistanceDP(range.getValue().toString().toLowerCase(),sh.getRange("K3").getValue()].toString().toLowerCase()))  //change 10 with the number of column you desire to use as auxiliar for this}
   }
 }

}
```

When you change K3 it will re-calculate all the column once, when you change a value in column H it will only calculate that row once. Try it and let me know. You may share a sample file with the functions to debug if necessary

Comment: Oh of course. That makes a lot more sense! Thanks. I should manage to do that - just didnt cross my mind!

Comment: Actually one thing: The script runs super slowly, i tried to improve that, by not printing it to the the sheets row by row but once in the end, i'm still only getting to around 400 rows (instead of maybe 20 with your method) [Edit: Because of the 30sec runtime limit] . Most certainly thats because of the potentially rather ineffective levenshtein algorithm, which becomes quite slow, when my strings are between 5 and 30 chars. Is there any other straight forward way to check for similarity?

Comment: Nevermind. The algorithm is fast enough, and when you only print it in the end it works fine within a handful of seconds for several thousands of rows. One has to be aware tho, that the returned array by getValues is 2 dimensional rather than one-dimensional which.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! For the last comment it's why I said to share your sheet to debug if necessary, I just wrote it by heart y and it may had its small issues